# Including custom font with mpdf does not show fonts in Adobe Acrobat on Windows but does on Okular

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, mpdf

When I include my custom fonts (as specified below) with mPDF, the custom fonts are correctly used in the PDF when viewed in Okular (a Linux PDF reader) and Chrome's built in PDF viewer, *but* on Windows, Adobe Acrobat falls back to `Helvetica`, not my custom font.

Could it be that mPDF is writing the font instructions in a non-standard manner? Or am I doing something wrong?

I'm including them according to these instructions: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=501

*Assumes you have 2 font files "Frutiger-Normal.ttf" and "FrutigerObl-Normal.ttf" which you want to be available in mPDF, and you will refer to them in HTML/CSS as "Frutiger".*

*1.* Upload the 2 files to the fonts directory (/ttfonts)

*2.* In the configuration file (config_fonts.php) add this to the array `$this->fontdata`:

```
"frutiger" => array(
    'R' => "Frutiger-Normal.ttf",
    'I' => "FrutigerObl-Normal.ttf",
),
```

*3.* In your HTML or CSS code use something like this:

```
<p style="font-family: Frutiger">....</p>
```

Comment: Do you actually embed the font files themselves inside the pdf document or do you just reference the fonts in the document?

Comment: @arkascha just reference them. how do i embed them in the PDF?

Comment: @arkascha Reading the manual: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=501 what I do (explained above) should be embedding it.

Comment: Can you create a test PDF and post a link to it? That way we can try and see what instructions end up (or don't) in the PDF.

Comment: If you just reference them you will always run into issues, since the PDF interpreter obviously can only use fonts installed on the system where the PDF is opened and also only fonts found under exactly the same name. PDFs allow to "embed" whole font files into the PDF itself, given that every PDF interpreter should be able to render the fonts correctly, regardless of what fonts are locally installed. All PDF libraries offer that, you have to look for that option. I never used mPDF, only tcPDF myself, and that worked just fine.